# Why my machine, automatically goes to this IP/domains

Tags: url, dns, ip-address, bing

Why my machine, automatically goes to this IP*domains. I have installed VM with windows 7 and I have wordpress site with xammp server and that is all. Is they are safe domains or not? Because I see bing.com in the end of the first domain.

`1.foodanddrink.tile.appex.bing.com
2.init-p01md-lb.push-apple.com.akadns.net
IP- 95.180.157.187 or 95.180.157.193`

Are anyone has same issue is that are some services from Microsoft, apple or are some bad links.
When I googled for first domain I found this.

https://www.threatcrowd.org/domain.php?domain=foodanddrink.tile.appex.bing.com

Comment: How is this programming related?

Comment: For the second one you should AskDifferent
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174168/what-is-http-init-p01st-push-apple-com

Comment: Hint: there is also sports.tile.appex.bing.com

Comment: OK but why make many attempts to access that host address 'almost every hour in average'

Comment: Second one is for Push Messages as stated in link. First one is to enhance your windows user experience.

Comment: "Because I see bing.com in the end of the first domain" That does not matter. The `PTR` records of an IP address can be set to arbitrary names. So when you translate an IP back to a name, you have no guarantees. You would need to translate the name back to an IP and they if the result matches the original. But it will also happen to be false for many perfectly normal configurations.

Comment: [This question on Apple SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/358641)

Answer (score 2):

These are usually related to malwares. Check your installed programs, running processes (in the task manager), installed plugin on browsers, nulled plugins and null themes installed on Wordpress and uninstall any unknown and suspicious applications.

Comment: Hi, could you provide info on how you conclude those links are related to malwares?

Comment: Sure. There are many fake URLs like those mentioned above that does not even exist. For example, you can see many URLs similar to "foodanddrink.tile.appex.bing.com" mentioned in the question in this address: [link](https://otx.alienvault.com/indicator/hostname/foodanddrink.tile.appex.bing.com?utm_medium=InProduct&utm_source=ThreatCrowd) `passive DNS` section. Thanks for edits btw